# Searching all nodes for xml column

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to search all the nodes in an sql xml column.

For example if i have the following XML

```
<ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <EntityPropertyOfString>
    <Name>User Label 1</Name>
    <Value>TX 12107210</Value>
  </EntityPropertyOfString>
  <EntityPropertyOfString>
    <Name>User Label 2</Name>
    <Value>BONUS $350/DAY</Value>
  </EntityPropertyOfString>
  <EntityPropertyOfString>
    <Name>User Defined Date 9</Name>
    <Value>11/09/2011</Value>
  </EntityPropertyOfString>
</ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString>
```

How can I search for all values that contain the word 'bonus'??

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
declare @xml xml =
'<ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <EntityPropertyOfString>
  <Name>User Label 1</Name>
  <Value>TX 12107210</Value>
 </EntityPropertyOfString>
<EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>User Label 2</Name>
<Value>BONUS $350/DAY</Value>
</EntityPropertyOfString>
<EntityPropertyOfString>
<Name>User Defined Date 9</Name>
<Value>11/09/2011</Value>
 </EntityPropertyOfString>
 </ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString>'

select T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as NodeName,
       T.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NodeValue
from @xml.nodes('//*') as T(N)
where T.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%bonus%'
```

Result:

```
NodeName             NodeValue
-------------------- --------------------
Value                BONUS $350/DAY
```

For a table it could look like this:

```
declare @T table (ID int identity primary key, XMLCol xml)

declare @xml xml =
'<ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <EntityPropertyOfString>
     <Name>User Label 1</Name>
     <Value>TX 12107210</Value>
   </EntityPropertyOfString>
   <EntityPropertyOfString>
     <Name>User Label 2</Name>
     <Value>BONUS $350/DAY</Value>
   </EntityPropertyOfString>
   <EntityPropertyOfString>
     <Name>User Defined Date 9</Name>
     <Value>11/09/2011</Value>
   </EntityPropertyOfString>
 </ArrayOfEntityPropertyOfString>'

insert into @T values (@xml)
insert into @T values (@xml)

select T1.ID,
       T2.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(max)') as NodeName,
       T2.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NodeValue
from @T as T1
  cross apply T1.XMLCol.nodes('//*') as T2(N)  
where T2.N.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%bonus%'
```

Result:

```
ID          NodeName             NodeValue
----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           Value                BONUS $350/DAY
2           Value                BONUS $350/DAY
```

Comment: The alias `T(N)` and `T.N` are unrecognizable on my installation.

Comment: This seems like it will work, but only for one record. I want to query the entire table.

Comment: Is there an easier way than looping through each record?

Comment: @Eric - Sure, you can use `cross apply`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @BZN_DBer You can try it here: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/121532/

Answer (score 0):

If you can make the assumption that bonus will never occur in a tag...

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ...
WHERE COL_NAME LIKE '%bonus%'
```

Comment: Actually, there will be Bonus TAgs. I'm trying to get all the bonus values out of the Value nodes and insert them into the Bonus Nodes.